# Can frictional force be un-aligned with wind direction?

Tags: meteorology, wind, atmosphere-modelling, planetary-boundary-layer

There is a well known solution to Navier-Stokes equations for atmospheric boundary layer according to Ekman (see for instance PalArya's book "Introduction to Micrometeorology" or Holton's "Introduction to dynamic Meteorology"):
[image]

$u_g$ is the geostrophic wind (assumed in x direction), u, v denote the real wind components , $\gamma=\sqrt{f/2\nu}$, f=Coriolis parameter, $\nu$ denotes viscosity.

By plotting this z-behavior of u and v I made the observation, that frictional force is in general **not antiparallel** to the wind. Taking the extreme z=0, wind is even zero and there must be a balance of frictional force with Coriolis force. In the following graph the vectors of real wind $\vec v$ (green), geostrophic wind $\vec v_g$ (red) and ageostrophic wind $\vec v_a$ (yellow) are drawn together with the forces for total Coriolis (dotted green), negative pressure gradient force (dotted red) and frictional force (dotted yellow).

I'm surprised that in this solution the frictional force (as calculated from second derivatives of u and v with regard to z) is not parallel to the overall wind, even though it is the case in many meteorology books and online material, e.g. B. [here](https://apollo.nvu.vsc.edu/classes/met130/notes/chapter8/fr_aloft_gr.html). Why is there such a “discrepancy” between the Ekman solution above and what we find elsewhere?

I find it a bit counterintuitive that friction is not aligned with the wind direction. Could it be that I have a misunderstanding?

[image]